# Will these laptop displays fit into each other?

Tags: laptop, display, compatibility

I found a LCD panel that's a perfect replacement for my laptop Acer Aspire 5738G. It's relatively cheap, and it's from a laptop named Acer eMachines E727.

I have only one question. Will it work with my laptop?

They are both look the same have the same dimensions and resolution, and both have a 40-pin connection.

I don't want to buy a LCD panel that doesn't work with my laptop.

Comment: if you have a picture of the panel you want to buy, then take apart your machine and look if they are the same. Count the screws, stuff like that. Typically with screens that are very similar in different machines, the actual panels will be the same. Other way is to contact the seller, chances are they can answer your question a lot better (when you ask take your screen out and look for a model/serial number, that way you can compare them with the panel you want to buy). Good Luck